# How to access LAN devices from inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, networking, wsl-2

There is a device in my LAN that I want to access from docker container.

I think it should just work but here some of debugging results

WHAT WORKS

1. Host has access to the device. I can curl wget ping it all work just fine from the machine I host my docker containers one.
2. Container can access the internet. I can ping wget google.com works fine.

WHAT DOES NOT WORK

Accessing the device from the container hosted on machine that can access the device.
I am using a local ip 192.168.0.141 to access my device. By default container is in bridge network mode and it should work fine but just in case I created a separate bridge network and added it `docker run -it --rm --net=my-net` it just hands on connecting. I also tried host `docker run -it --rm --net=host` ping returns a router IP.

Here is the container I have been having trouble with but other containers like... ubuntu do not work too
https://github.com/vitalets/docker-tizen-webos-sdk
`docker run -it --rm -v tvdata:/home/developer vitalets/tizen-webos-sdk bash`

Host is Windows WSL2

Comment: How are you trying to connect to it?  One thing I've observed in a couple of other questions is that if you use a simple host name `device` then Docker's DNS layer intercepts it and tries to interpret it as a container name, so you must use a FQDN `device.example.com`.  Otherwise default Docker networking settings should work fine.

Comment: Well I am trying to ping them first or curl a web page it is hosting also would like a socket but since I can not even ping it...